# Can you group multiple network locations into one folder?

Tags: windows-10, networking, shared-folders, sharing

I regularly have to access a group of about 12+ network locations, which I usually do by entering their ip address in file explorer. However there are so many locations that its getting a bit long winded to do this each time, and try to remember which ip is which machine.

I was going to add named network locations to make this easier, but it just means I now have a very long list of locations in windows explorer.

Is there any way to put these locations into a single folder, or group them together, so that I can tidy it up a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create regular `.lnk` shortcuts and organize them in your preferred folders. (Right-click in a folder, select "New > Shortcut", enter the UNC path that you want to add.)

That's really what the 'Network Locations' section *is* anyway – special display for a folder full of shortcuts. You can find it at `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts`. Creating a subfolder there would in fact make it show up under "Network locations" in the "This PC" page.

[image]